# Excel Parent Child

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I've researched this issue thoroughly through the questions and answers currently available and I'm at the conclusion that my issue is unique.

I have an Excel spreadsheet with 2 columns.  Column A contains a Parent and Column B contains children.  The format of the spreadsheet is similar to:

[Parent Child Excel example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sbRdJ.jpg)

What I'm trying to accomplish is create a CSV showing a child followed by one or more of its parents, such as (from table above):

[CSV example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NZpZw.jpg)

Each child has at least 1 parent, but can have many parents.

The spreadsheet currently has 49,000 rows.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to do it with formulas in 2 columns, which you can unite into one.

Formula for `C2` (drag to all column cells):

```
=IF(A2<>A1,B2,C1 & "," & B2)
```

Formula for `D2` (drag to all column cells):

```
=IF(A2<>A3,CONCATENATE(A2,",""",C2,""""),"")
```

Result:

[image]

I used the result format `<CHILD>,"<PARENT1><PARENT2>....<PARENTn>"` but you can change the format as you wish in the `CONCATENTATE` function,

Comment: This gives all children of each parent, whereas questioner wanted all parents of each child. The solution (which I liked) can be easily adapted though. Sort the data in order of Child then Parent and swap the Parent and Child columns around.  Everything can be done in column `C` with `=IF(A2<>A1,A2 & "," & B2, C1 & "," & B2)` in `C2` (and dragged down). If `D2` is set to `=A2<>A3` (and dragged down) then output is rows of `C` for which `D` is `TRUE.`

Answer (score 0):

this look like a good solution for your problem or future people comming on this thread in search of solution.

https://www.mrexcel.com/board/threads/parent-child-sorting-like-a-tree-for-requirements-tracking.1201614/

VBA Code:

```
Option Explicit
Sub Parents()
    Dim lr As Long, x As Long, y As Long, z As Long
    Dim rng1 As Range, rng2 As Range, c As Range
    lr = Cells(Rows.Count, "B").End(3).Row
    Set rng1 = Range("B2:B" & lr)
    Set rng2 = Range("C2:C" & lr)
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

For Each c In rng2
    If c <> "" Then
        x = Application.Match(c, rng1, 0) + 1
        rng1.Cells(x, 1).Resize(1, 3).Insert xlShiftDown
        With c.Offset(, -1).Resize(1, 3)
            .Copy rng1.Cells(x, 1)
            .Delete xlShiftUp
        End With
    End If
Next c

Set rng2 = Range("C3:C" & lr)
For Each c In rng2
    If c <> "" Then
        y = Right(c, 1)
        z = Right(c.Offset(-1, -1), 1)
        If z > y Then
            c.Offset(-1, -1).Resize(1, 3).Insert xlShiftDown
            With c.Offset(, -1).Resize(1, 3)
                .Select
                .Copy c.Offset(-2, -1)
                .Delete xlShiftUp
            End With
        End If
    End If
Next c

For Each c In rng1
    If c.Offset(, 1) <> "" Then
        c = Chr(32) & Chr(32) & c
        If Right(c.Offset(-1, 1), 1) <> "" And Right(c.Offset(, 1), 1) > Right(c.Offset(-1, 1), 1) Then
            c = Chr(32) & Chr(32) & c
        End If
    End If
Next c

Application.ScreenUpdating = True
```

End Sub